# Как написать клиент-сервер на java, используя внешний ip?

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер

Я **начинающий** в программировании, и решил сделать простое клиент-серверное приложение. Хочется разобраться, как можно передавать данные между сервером и клиентом, которые имеют разные внешние ip (проще говоря - через интернет).

Вот код моего сервера:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server {

    private static ServerSocket server;

    private static Socket connection;
    private static ObjectOutputStream output;
    private static ObjectInputStream input;
    private static Boolean isAlreadyConnected = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            server = new ServerSocket(6666, 100);

            while(true) {
                connection = server.accept();

                if(!isAlreadyConnected) {
                    System.out.println("Connected");
                    isAlreadyConnected = true;
                }

                output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                output.flush();
                input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

                String message = (String) input.readObject();

                System.out.println("User sent you: " + message);
                output.writeObject("Your message: " + message);
                output.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Probably something wrong with connection. Application will be switched off.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            close();
        }
    }

    // Don't know if it's necessary:
    private static void close() {
        try {
            output.close();
            input.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот мой клиент:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dispatcher implements Runnable {

    private static Socket connection;
    private static ObjectOutputStream output;
    private static ObjectInputStream input;
    private static Scanner scanner;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Dispatcher()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {

            while(true) {
//                Next line means connection to this computer
                connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 6666);

//                TODO: Connection by external IP
//                connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("91.243.199.142"), 6666);

                output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                output.flush();
                input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

                sendData(scanner.nextLine());

                System.out.println(input.readObject());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void sendData(Object object)  {
        try {
            output.flush();
            output.writeObject(object);
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Можете сказать, как переделать этот код, чтоб я мог подключиться на компьютер у которого другой внешний ip? Или подскажите, как это можно сделать другим способом, желательно на Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему таким образом:
Скачал ngrok, отрыл порт. На 0.tcp.ngrok.io выделился порт, на который можно отправить запрос, который будет перенаправляться на сервер. Получилась такая строка в клиенте:

```
connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("0.tcp.ngrok.io"), 16824);
```

Последнее число в конструкторе - порт, который выдаст тебе консоль ngrok'ка.

Answer (score -1):

Код сервера - да никак... по крайней мере на внешнем (глобальном) IP он и так поднимается, но только если тот белый (за этим - к провайдеру или vps купите).
Ну и на локальном (вида 192.168.*.*), наверное, тоже (для локального не требуется ничего, кроме роутера, к которому подключены оба компьютера, какой именно IP у каждого - узнается по-разному на разных ОС).
**Единственное - во всех случаях должен быть открыт порт в брандмауэре (в глобальном - точно), а также для глобального - в роутере.**
Ну, еще можно точно задавать IP, чтобы не путаться вот так и точно знать, вышло поднять на нем или нет.

(Еще хороший сервер должен бы сам разруливать в случае с брандмауэром, или хотя бы при неудачном запуске узнавать, в этом ли проблема или в чем-то другом. Но это имело бы смысл только в продукте вроде Apache, т.е. который бы поднимали много раз на совсем разных компьютерах. И с кроссплатформенной Java эта виндокухня как-то не сочетается.)

Главное - указывать клиенту IP сервера вместо localhost.

Comment: Внешний ip нужно узнавать у провайдера? Нельзя ввести в гугле "ip", и получить его?

Comment: @VladislavSavelyev Нет такой необходимости, любой сервер его видит когда подключаетесь к нему, много специальных сервисов которые его показывают, тот же 2ip.ru, это и есть внешний

Comment: Воспользовался ngrok (см. ответ)